# How can I view the traffic time graph in my browser for Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome

I can't find the graph showing trip time vs departure time when using maps.google.com in Chrome on my PC.

I can easily find it in the Android App though, I just get directions (not navigation) and then swipe up for more information. See below:

[image: Google Maps Traffic Graph]

Is this available through a browser, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

On the top left corner you find and click the "burger menu" (three parallel lines)

[image: Google maps traffic graph Desktop]

Once there, you click and activate the traffic graph (it turns light blue).

Following that, you can find the traffic graph on the bottom of the map (in the middle of it) with an option for either `Live traffic`

[image: Google maps Live traffic graph Desktop]

or `Typical traffic`

[image: Google maps Typical traffic graph Desktop]

Comment: That doesn't actually show a graph of trip time vs departure time. The graph I posted shows how the trip time increases as the departure time becomes later. What you have posted just shows colors on the roads.

Comment: You are correct. I am afraid though that you can NOT find that on a desktop. I guess it is considered a static device.

Comment: @marikamitsos, but is the device the deciding factor?  Isn't it simply a difference between using a web browser versus a dedicated app?